# GCP Cloud Storage upload file SaveOptions onUploadProgress only callback one time

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to get the progress when I upload file to GCP cloud storage by Node.js.
I found there is an onUploadProgress in SaveOptions, but this is only callback one time.

```
        storage.bucket(bucket_name).file(file_path).save(buffers, {
                onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                    console.log(progressEvent)
                }
            }
        )
```

And the progressEvent value is like below, and bytesWritten's value is the file size.

```
{ bytesWritten: 80248835, contentLength: '*' }
```

Is it possible to get the realtime upload progress event from Node.js client library? (@google-cloud/storage)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I can received many times callback after I add chunkSize.

```
const chunkSize = 8 * 1024 * 1024;
storage.bucket(bucket_name).file(file_path).save(buffers, { chunkSize: chunkSize,
        onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
            console.log(progressEvent)
        }
    }
)
```